# How to change position of columns in attribute table?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

If I have an attribute table with columns A B C D, is it possible to move the columns to different positions, say, B C A D? When making a new column with the field calculator it would be useful to put it somewhere other than last position or to be able to move key columns close to it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Plugin 'Table Manager' does what you want.

Answer (score 23):

There is now a build in solution, called `Refactor fields`, you can find it in the `Processing Toolbox` under `Vector table tools`.

The as solution marked `table editor plugin` is no longer a working solution as it's being deprecated.

Comment: The refactor tool permanently does the table order change. thanks

Answer (score -1):

As far as I am aware the Table Manager does not handle layers in SHP format. So it also depends on where you data sits. If you data is in SHP format, you could open the corresponding DBF file in Excel or Open/Libre Office and change the position of the columns.

Comment: The table manager works perfectly with shapefiles, you don't even have to save the changes to a new file but can keep the current one. Working in OO/Libre would work just fine, too, but take care not to resort your dbf-file without being able to restore the original sorting (e.g. by using a feature id field) or the shapefile will show wrong attributes for each feature.

Comment: I have had mixed results with fooling with the .shp file's .dbf. And once it gets altered there seems to be no recovery. If I had my files in a spatial database (which I know nothing about) would I be able to arrange the columns?

Comment: I misunderstood what you were saying. I just tried to find TableManager and I found the .zip on http://pyqgis.org/repo/contributed however it does not appear in my plugin manager list which includes the offical one. I have had this problem before, Sextante did not appear until I used QGIS on another machine. Never did install it correctly.

Comment: Simpliest way is to add http://pyqgis.org/repo/contributed to the list of repos (Plugins->Install Python Plugins, second tab, Add..) and make sure it is checked active in Plugins->Plugin Manager -- or what its called in English version...