# Reordering of layer properties fields in QGIS possible?

Tags: qgis, layers, fields-attributes, order

I'm wondering why such simple things are not possible.

I have 5 fields on my layer and the last one shall be on the top now. But there is no way to do this, is this correct?

Comment: What spatial format is your layer in? If it's a shapefile, this is one of the limitations of shapefiles, and QGIS is no different than other GIS software in its inability to reorder fields. I think ESRI just recently added this capability to ArcGIS.

Comment: The layer is a Shapefile layer. Mhh I was thinking that this is simply a visual issue, so it's more than this?

Comment: Looks like I was wrong, QGIS can do this with a plugin: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31555/how-to-change-position-of-columns-in-attribute-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, load your Shapefile to QGIS and then use the [Table Manager plugin](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/tablemanager) to order the Shapefile fields as you want. Finally, click on Save.

Comment: Broken link, perhasp this is the subtitution : http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/tablemanager/

Note in the link:
This plugin was created as a workaround for removing and renaming columns in dbf tables, when there was no built-in solution in QGIS. Currently, its development is depreciated, so please consider using the Refactor Field algorithm from the Pocessing panel (advanced interface).